# Get user Coordinates in iOS simulator at the app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I was asked to code a small app for iOS in Objective C that's supposed to choose the closest object of a user, in a set of coordinates 
The plan was to load the coordinates of the user only once, when the application loads for the first time.
Here's my current code :

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self.userLat = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    self.userLon = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@" ----------------------------- ");
    NSLog(@"User lat : %lf", self.userLat);
    NSLog(@"User lon : %lf", self.userLon);
    NSLog(@" ----------------------------- ");
}
```

I don't have a Apple iOS developper program, so I'm stuck with the iOS simulator from xCode.
I try to set some custom coordinates in the iOS simulator through debug, like this : 
[image]
When i execute the app (obviously after setting coordinates), the log has userLat and userLon to 0.00..

```
Apr  6 03:16:20 Locals-Mac.local app[5683]:  ----------------------------- 
Apr  6 03:16:20 Locals-Mac.local app[5683]: User lat : 0.000000
Apr  6 03:16:20 Locals-Mac.local app[5683]: User lon : 0.000000
Apr  6 03:16:20 Locals-Mac.local app[5683]:  -----------------------------
```

I remember hearing somewhere that the iOS simulator don't work with the CoreLocation library (It might be right or wrong, i wouldn't know). 
Is it the reason the lat/lon values are 0?
If the reason is indeed the iOS simulator, does this code give user current location?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit :

With the answer and comments, i'm now using the didUpdateLocations callback function :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    self.userLat = location.coordinate.latitude;
    self.userLon = location.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@" ----------------------------- ");
    NSLog(@"User lat : %lf", self.userLat);
    NSLog(@"User lon : %lf", self.userLon);
    NSLog(@" ----------------------------- ");
}
```

I ask xCode to simulate my position to London with the Scheme option that follows : 
[image]
My new load function :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

This code still doesn't print the NSLog that was put in the location callback function. Did i miss something?

Comment: You can try to use a gpx with coordinates and set your app to simulate its location based on the gpx on the project scheme.

Comment: I did update my 1st post, but it seems i still can't get my pos even if i ask my project to simulate a position, could you check my update please? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The location manager doesn't instantly have the user's location when you start updating it.  If you check the `location` property right after calling `startUpdatingLocation` it is usually going to be `nil` unless some other app was recently updating it.  You need to implement the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method which will be called once it has a location.

You also need to check and possibly request for location permissions.

Comment: didUpdateLocations will update location continuously, right? Is there a way to get the information only once?

Comment: You can call `stopUpdatingLocation` after you get the first location update.